# java : Sum of Vertical elements in a triangle

Tags: java

I want to calculate the sum of all vertical elements in an triangle for example, if the triangle is

Ex : Triangle size is 5

```
1
2 2
5 2 2
2 0 5 8
8 7 9 4 5
```

Then the sum should be

```
Sum1 = 1+2+5+2+8 = 18 (Sum of vertical elements from the first column)
Sum2 = 2+2+0+7 = 11
Sum3 = 2+5+9 = 16
Sum4 = 8+4=  12
Sum5 = 5 = 5
```

Note : The triangle size will vary, also the elements will be random.

Program I wrote, but it's only calculating the first row how do i calculate and store the 2nd, 3rd and upto the last ?

```
public class fsdhs 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int arr[]={1,2,2,5,2,2,2,0,5,8,8,7,9,4,5};
        int x,y,count=0,size=5,sum=0;
        boolean flag=false;
        for(x=0;x<size;x++)
        {
            for(y=0;y<=x;y++)
               {
                if(flag==false)
                {
                    sum=sum+arr[count];
                    flag=true;
                }
                 System.out.print(arr[count]+" ");
                 count++;
               }            
               System.out.print("\n");
               flag=false;
        }
        System.out.print("\nSum1="+sum);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more intuitive approach may be to use a multidimensional jagged array to store the triangle data. This way you can reason over the coordinates directly without needing to calculate row based offsets:

```
int arr[][]={{1},{2,2},{5,2,2},{2,0,5,8},{8,7,9,4,5}};

int size=5;

for(int x=0; x < size; x++)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int y=x; y < size; y++)
    {
        sum += arr[y][x];
    }
    System.out.println("Column " + x + " Sum=" + sum + "\n");
}
```

You just need to be wary of the uneven row sizes of the jagged array

[IdeOne Demo](https://ideone.com/2MoRB1)

Comment: You are a genius, never thought of that :P

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify your code and calculate col sums using the following formula to get index of array by index of i-th row in triangle and j-th column (j<=i, zero-based):

```
index = i*(i+1)/2 + j
```

For example, in given triangle at row i=3, column j=2 value is 5, so
index = 3*4/2 + 2 = 8, arr[8] is also 5

Answer (score 2):

```
int SIZE = 5; // The size of your triangle
int arr[]={1,2,5,2,8,2,2,0,7,2,5,9,8,4,5}; // Array of triangle items
int[] sums = new int[SIZE];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i += SIZE, SIZE--) {
    for(int j = i; j < i + SIZE; j++) {
        sums[sums.length - SIZE] += arr[j];
    }
}

// Show items
for (int i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("item " + i + ": " + sums[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Output I am getting from your code is
item 0: 12
item 1: 9
item 2: 23
item 3: 13
item 4: 5

the sum of all cols are not correct :\

Comment: @prateek569 I updated the array to contain the same elements as yours. It should be good now.

Comment: You're welcome. I tried to write very simple code so that you easily understand it.